# How to hold execution of python script until window is closed?

Tags: python

Here I my script:

```
import pyke
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shutil import copyfile

class star:

    def __init__(self, path, name,definedaper=False):
        self.path=path
        self.name=name

        self.infile=path+name
        self.maskout = self.infile+'_maskout'

    def aperdef(self):
            plt.interactive(True)

            %matplotlib
            pyke.kepmask(self.infile)
            # WAIT HERE UNTIL MATPLOTLIB WINDOW CLOSED
            copyfile('maskfile.txt',self.maskout)


    def loadaper(self):
        with open('maskfile.txt') as f:
            maskfile = f.read()
        f.closed
        cords=maskfile.split("|")[5]
        cordlist=cords.split(";")

        cordlistmat=[]
        for index, line in enumerate(cordlist):
            cordlistmat.append(line.split(","))


def main():
    ourstar = star('/home/pal/konkoly/go10037/','ktwo201085427-c101_lpd-targ.fits')
    ourstar.aperdef() 

    ourstar.loadaper()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The `pyke.kepmask(self.infile)` will open a window, with which the user can interact, and create a file maskfile.txt though this window. I want the script **not to go for** `copyfile('maskfile.txt',self.maskout)`, **until** this **window is closed**.
How can I achieve that? Something better than constantly checking maskfile.txt exists or not, and then wait if it does not?

The file I use for input, in the line `ourstar = star('/home/pal/konkoly/go10037/','ktwo201085427-c101_lpd-targ.fits')` is available here:
https://github.com/zabop/starclass_pub/blob/master/ktwo201085427-c101_lpd-targ.fits